# Java URI class: constructor determines whether or not query is encoded?

Tags: java, uri

Is this behavior intentional?

```
//create the same URI using two different constructors

URI foo = null, bar = null;
try { 
    //constructor: URI(uri string)
    foo = new URI("http://localhost/index.php?token=4%2F4EzdsSBg_4vX6D5pzvdsMLDoyItB");
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {} 
try { 
    //constructor: URI(scheme, authority, path, query, fragment) 
    bar = new URI("http", "localhost", "/index.php", "token=4%2F4EzdsSBg_4vX6D5pzvdsMLDoyItB", null);
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {}

//the output:
//foo.getQuery() = token=4/4EzdsSBg_4vX6D5pzvdsMLDoyItB
//bar.getQuery() = token=4%2F4EzdsSBg_4vX6D5pzvdsMLDoyItB
```

The URI(string uri) constructor seems to be decoding the query part of the URI. I thought the query portion is supposed to be encoded? And why doesn't the other constructor decode the query part?

Comment: Could you please correct your formatting to make your post more readable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [URI JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#legal-chars):

> The single-argument constructor requires any illegal characters in its argument to be quoted and preserves any escaped octets and other characters that are present.
>
> The multi-argument constructors quote illegal characters as required by the components in which they appear. The percent character ('%') is always quoted by these constructors. Any other characters are preserved.

Thus URI(String) expects you to encode everything correctly and assumes `%2F` is such an encoded octed which will be decoded to `/`.

The other constructors would endcode the `%` character (resulting in `%252F` for input `%2F`) and thus after decoding you still get `%2F`.

I assume the purpose of the deviation between the constructors is to allow things like `new URI(otherUri.toString())` with `toString()` returning a fully encoded URI.

Comment: This is interesting. Thank you. I'll remember to refer to Oracle's JavaDoc. The documentation in the Android reference is much more sparse in comparison.

Answer (score 0):

A quick analysis:

**foo**

The constructor parses the input URI and unquotes the literal `%2F` to `/`. This is what we expect.

**bar**

With the constructor used in the bar example, the *fragment* part is taken as a raw String with illegal chars and *encoded* first, with the effect that `%2F` is translated to `%252F`. *Then* it is parsed and the now unquoted query part is (again) `%2F`.

Lesson learned: With the first constructor we pass an RFC 2396 compliant URI. The other constructors take *normal* Strings (unquoted illegal chars) and `URI` constructs an RFC 2396 compliant representation.

[Here's a working example on IDEONE (with extra supporting output)](http://ideone.com/iNuPl)

Comment: (recieved a real life `InterruptedException` so the answer is a bit late, but I leave it because of the ideone link, which supports Thomas's answer too)